# C++ How can I find the mode(s) of an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, mode

I have to write a function that finds the mode of an array of values for class. It takes two arguments: the array of values and a variable equal to the number of valid values in the array. It sounded easy enough but after a week of trying I can't seem to my code work.

The idea is to take the one dimensional array and store it in a 2 dimensional array where the first value is a value from the array of values and the second is the number of times that value occurs. So far it isn't working quite right, or at all. The problem feels like it should be obvious but I've been stumped for a week.

I'm testing it with an array containing the following:
9.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.0, 6.0, 6.0, 6.0, 7.0, 1.0, 9.0, 10.0

Code:

```
void mode(double x[], const int n)
{
    int j, k, m=1, p, numofmodes=0;
    bool match=false, breaker;
    double y[100][2]={0}, max=0;



    y[0][0] = x[0];
    y[0][1] = 1;

    for(j=1; j<=(n-1); j++)  //
    {
        for (k=0; k<=(m-1); k++)
            if (x[j] == y[k][0])
            {
                y[k][1]++;
                match = true;
            }

        if (match == false)
        {
            y[m][0] = x[j];
            y[m][1] = 1;
            m++;
        }
        match = false;
    }



    for(j=0; j<=(n-1); j++)
    {
        if (y[j][1] > max)
            max = y[j][1];
    }

    for(j=0; j<=(n-1); j++)
    {
        if (y[j][1] = max)
            numofmodes++;
    }


    for(j=0; j<=(n-1); j++)
    {
        cout<<y[j][0]<<"    "<<y[j][1]<<endl;
    }


    cout<<"There are "<<numofmodes<< " modes in the data set."<<endl;

    for(j=0; j<=(n-1); j++)
    {
        if (y[j][1] = max)
        {
            cout<<y[j][0]<<" appears "<<max<<" times."<<endl;
        }
    }

}
```

Output:
9    2
0    2
0    2
0    2
0    2
0    2
0    2
0    2
0    2
0    2
0    2
0    2
0    2
There are 13 modes in the data set.
9 appears 2 times.
0 appears 2 times.
0 appears 2 times.
0 appears 2 times.
0 appears 2 times.
0 appears 2 times.
0 appears 2 times.
0 appears 2 times.
0 appears 2 times.
0 appears 2 times.
0 appears 2 times.
0 appears 2 times.
0 appears 2 times.

Comment: The indent on your second paragraph makes it code.

Comment: `if (match = false)`: `=` should be `==`. `false == match` also works. Also, look at how you are using `m`, you set it to 1 at the start but never change it.

Comment: Since you're using C++, not C, you should use an STL map rather than an array. The key is the number, the value is the count of matches.

Comment: This looks like an assignment. I think they want him to learn how to do this by himself.

Comment: One thing that will help you catch logical errors in C/C++ like the (Match = false) is to switch the values in the test like so `(if false == match)`.  If the test was built like that, it would have thrown a compilation error, and that error would have been easier to spot.

Comment: I fixed the `(match = false)` problem. Now I'm getting different junk output. Everything _looks_ like it should work, but its not.

Comment: If you fixed it, you might want to update the question as well.

Comment: If you sorted the array first, you could run through the array a final time and for the current value while it's not changing count the number of times it appears.  If count > current mode, set current mode = count.

Comment: The passed in array can't be > 100 items!  you need assert(n < 100) or something.

Answer (score 0):

2 x `if (y[j][1] = max)` - Similar to the (match = false) issue - At this point `max` is 2 and so ever value is overwritten by 2.

The problem with the first column sounds like it is due to the `match = false` issue. Is it still occurring after you fixed it and recompiled?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it. I included the main function its written to work with here.

Input1.txt:
9.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.0, 6.0, 6.0, 6.0, 6.0, 6.0, 6.0, 7.0, 1.0, 9.0, 10.0, 4.0, -9999

I changed a few `=` to `==` and fixed a math error in one of the for loops, and now I do appear to be... golden. Aurum est potestas. :D

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
void mode(double x[], const int n);
using namespace std;

int main()
{
        const int N = 100;
        double x[N];
        void mode (double x[],int n);
        int n;
        ifstream inFile;

        inFile.open("input1.txt");
        n=0;
        inFile>>x[n];
        while (x[n]!=-9999)
        {
            n++;
            inFile >>x[n];
        }
        inFile.close( );
        mode(x,n);

        inFile.open("input2.txt");
        n=0;
        inFile >>x[n];
        while (x[n]!=-9999)
        {
            n++;
            inFile >>x[n];
        }
        inFile.close( );
        mode(x,n);



        inFile.open("input3.txt");
        n=0;
        inFile >>x[n];
        while (x[n]!=-9999)
        {
            n++;
            inFile >>x[n];
        }
        inFile.close( );
        mode(x,n);

        system ("PAUSE");
        return 0;
}






void mode(double x[], const int n)
{
    int j, k, m=1, p, numofmodes=0;
    bool match=false, breaker;
    double y[100][2]={0}, max=0;

    for(p=0;p<=n-1;p++)
    {
        y[p][0] = x[p];
        y[p][1]++;
    }


    for(j=1; j<=(n-1); j++)
    {
        for (k=0; k<=m; k++)
            if (x[j] == y[k][0])
            {
                y[k][1]++;
                match = true;
                cout<<y[k][0]<<"   "<<y[k][1]<<endl;
            }

        if (match == true)
        {
            y[m][0] = x[j];
            y[m][1] = 1;
            m++;
        }
        match = false;
    }



    for(j=0; j<=(n-1); j++)
    {
        if (y[j][1] > max)
            max = y[j][1];
    }

    for(j=0; j<=(n-1); j++)
    {
        if (y[j][1] == max)
            numofmodes++;
    }


    cout<<"There are "<<numofmodes<< " modes in the data set."<<endl;

    for(j=0; j<=(n-1); j++)
    {
        if (y[j][1] == max)
        {
            cout<<"The number "<<y[j][0]<<" appears "<<max<<" times."<<endl;
        }
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

Output:
There are 2 modes in the data set.
The number 4 appears 6 times.
The number 6 appears 6 times.

There are 2 modes in the data set.
The number 2 appears 3 times.
The number 5 appears 3 times.

There are 4 modes in the data set.
The number 1 appears 2 times.
The number 7 appears 2 times.
The number 19 appears 2 times.
The number 30 appears 2 times.

Press any key to continue . . .